# Issues connecting two data sources so that it shows data in the same graphs/tables when there is no data present in the main datasource

Tags: tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have a Oracle SQL script that I am reading into Tableau that is showing data on the Encounter Level. And I have an Excel File that contains budget numbers on a month/year level, what would be the best way to connect the two data sources ?

Essentially my Oracle database is a live feed that is summing up my encounters (daily,monthly, etc). And I have a budget file that is set for this fiscal year. Each row of my Excel file is representative of a budget number on the month/year level and specific to multiple categories (these categories are also present in my Oracle database).
My current issue is that: if there are no encounters for a category (ie. a filtered category with no visits in Dec 2020) then my budget from my excel file does not show in any of my tables/graphs.

Here is what I've tried:

1. I tried data blending between the two data sources
2. I tried outerjoining the two (while connecting on the categories that both can be filtered on).
3. The fixed calculation I used ( with Budget Excel file as the data source is) :

   - {fixed [Month],[FY],[Year],[Report Type],[MD]: avg([Budget MTD])}
   - I then a Sum Calculation of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following methods?

1. Analysis>Table Layout>Show Columns with no data
2. Analysis>Table Layout>Show Rows with no data